# How to filter out duplicate requests in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, foursquare

I am writing an iPhone app that integrates with Foursquare via OAuth.  I am able to log in, obtain an access token, and use the API endpoints.  I do the log in with a `UIWebView`.

The problem is that for every tap on the web view (Login, Allow, etc.), two identical requests are made.  So when I dismiss the web view after obtaining an access token, the web view's `didFailLoadWithError:` message fires, presumably for the second (duplicate) request.  This is causing crashes and unwanted behavior.

Is there any way I can prevent the duplicate requests from happening or can I 'filter' them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fa solution for filtering out: You can set the `delegate`-property of `UIWebView` to `nil` before dismissing it.

```
self.myWebView.delegate = nil;
self.myWebView = nil; //retain-property
```

**edit**: but this will not really prevent the `UIWebView` to send the second request over the wire. This will only end up with not being notified twice. You have to discover why the second request is sent.

Comment: Setting the delegate worked, thanks.  I'm not sure what is causing the duplicate requests.  I have almost identical code for my Facebook OAuth, and I didn't need to set the delegate to nil there.  Upon closer inspection there are duplicate requests in the Facebook sequence, too.  The difference with Foursquare is that the final request is never duplicated, while with Foursquare it is always duplicated.